# Migrate from activator 0.13.x to sbt 1.x

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator

I am migrating from activator from **0.13.x to sbt 1.x**.

I used to compile my modules like this `$ activator clean compile publish-local -Dversion=1`

Now, I am trying to do it with sbt since activator has been deprecated, but I can not find how I should migrate to something similar like `$ sbt clean compile publish-local -Dversion=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activator (the CLI part) was just a wrapper around sbt with some custom commands. So what you wrote should work the same, expect that the snake-case was deprecated in favor of the camelCase:

```
sbt clean compile publishLocal
```

If you need to pass a var to the Java runtime with `-D` you have to place it before any commands: `sbt -Dversion=1 ...`.

Notice that you use [batch mode](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Running.html#Batch+mode) to run the commands:

> Running in batch mode requires JVM spinup and JIT each time, so **your build will run much slower**. For day-to-day coding, we recommend using the sbt shell or Continuous build and test feature described below.

To follow this recommendation, just run `sbt` and then enter those commands one by one. Or to run them all sequentially, enter `; clean; compile; publishLocal`.

Comment: @agusgambina I saw that you accepted/unaccepted the answer. Did something go wrong?

Comment: it was throwing me an error, but researching it was a bug from sbt https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3050. So you were right, I will accept the question again

Comment: the other change I need to make was to put this sequence `sbt -Dversion=1 clean compile publishLocal`. The `-Dversion` is a parameter for `version := System.getProperty("version") ` in `build.sbt`

Comment: I see. Next time you can just comment on the answer if something doesn't work as you expect and get some help. I will modify the answer regarding `-Dversion`.